# How can I control css via document.referrer

Tags: javascript, html, css, referrer

I would like to automatically adjust the css if the visit comes from another site

```js
<script>
const ref = document.referrer.match("stackoverflow.com");
if (ref != null){
document.getElementByTagName("body").style.display = "none";
}
    </script>
```

The css in this way does not change, so what is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right approach, though `getElementByTagName()` is not a valid JavaScript method. Instead, you're looking for [`.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName), which returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) collection of elements (so you'll need to access the first index with `[0]`).

```js
const ref = document.referrer.match("stackoverflow.com");
if (ref != null) {
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.display = "none";
}
```